# Google and Bing safe search using Custom MDM solution for iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, mdm, emm

We are trying for Google safe search and Bing safe search on iPhone by applying restriction on iPhone from MDM server.

We have build custom MDM server and installed a profile on iPhone. Now we want to push settings to iPhones like Google/Bing safe search, allow/disallow internet access, etc.

We have tried to explored many articles, googled about it not did not find any solution.

Can someone let us know how to force user for google safe search and allow/disallow internet access? A link to any article/blog will also be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

For reference you can see this [video.](https://youtu.be/CTB0An-z-Xs?t=43)

Comment: You can refer to the Apple documentation for the policy items that you can enforce.   I don't believe that google safe search (which is a google web site setting) nor disabling internet are available policy settings.

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, I think so. I have searched a lot over internet but did not find a solution. Anyway thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am really amazed that how kidslox app did google and bing safe search. They are really restricting user on google and bing search engine. Any idea? https://youtu.be/CTB0An-z-Xs?t=43

Comment: I suspect that they are pushing an always-on VPN to the device, but that is just a guess

Comment: Possible, I have checked their iOS app. Event your iPhone is set on airplane mode the setting still applied on that device. I can see VPN written at top in iPhone screen.

Comment: Right, so if they are using a VPN then all traffic is routed through their server and they can modify, for example, search requests to enforce safe search.

Comment: okay....now I am understanding this how they are enforcing safe search, etc. on iPhone. Thanks for the help @Paulw11